# Does Jedis need to know all the cluster IPs to function or can it work with just one and let it figure out the others automatically?

Tags: jedis

I'm trying to connect to both a single node Redis and Elasticache cluster with the same code base.  I am using Jedis raw not via Spring since this is a legacy app and I am setting up Tomcat to use Jedis as a session store.

Does Jedis need to know all the cluster IPs to function or can it work with just one and let it figure out the others automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work with just one active node and then figuring out the other nodes internally.